# Convert the permissions in `ls -l` output to octal

Tags: bash, permissions

I want to convert the output of `ls` to octal permission bits.

I think of the shortest and clearest way to implement that excerise: Let's say that we have as input:

```
total 1
drwxr----x 1 user2 workers 1024 May 26 22:22 dir
-rwx-wxrw- 2 user2 workers 1024 May 26 22:22 file.txt
```

our output should be:

```
741 dir
736 file.txt
```

Comment: Please [Do not parse ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Kiwy I suspect that this is a homework exercise and the whole point is to parse a string like `drwxr----x`. The serious this-is-how-you-should-do-it-in-practice answers nicely illustrate how trying to disguise homework exercises can backfire.

Comment: I dont see a question...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas OK, if I had ever given such an answer I would remember that question, too...

Answer (score 9):

You could use GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f -printf "%m\t%f\n"
```

In order to obtain the complete path of the file, use the directive `p` instead of `f`:

```
find . -type f -printf "%m\t%p\n"
```

In order to restrict the results to the current directory, specify `-maxdepth`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%m\t%f\n"
```

If you want results both files and directories, remove the `-type` predicate:

```
find . -printf "%m\t%p\n"
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't want to use `ls` for this. On a GNU system, you could use:

```
stat -c'%a %n' *
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the clearest code but from the output quite easy to understand:

```
echo drwxr----x | 
awk '{chars=substr($1,2); print chars; gsub("-","0",chars); 
gsub("r","4",chars); gsub("w","2",chars); gsub("x","1",chars); 
print chars; for(i=1;i<10;i++) { sum+=substr(chars,i,1); 
if (i%3 == 0) { printf "%d",sum;sum=0; }; } print ""; }'

rwxr----x
421400001
741
```

(here assuming only the first 9 bits of the permissions are set)

Comment: @JosephR. The special bits would by a tiny adaption. In any case: Not the answer would be unjustified but the question. And of course we love to do others' homework...